# Properties in .NET WCF Service

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services

I'm having trouble using properties in a WCF service. I can define a property in the interface as:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://some-url.com/")]
interface ISomeInterface
{
  [OperationContract]
  int SomeMethod(string someArg);

  int SomeProperty
  {
    [OperationContract]
    get;
  }
}
```

But when consumed by a client, the property's underlying method `get_SomeProperty()` is exposed, rather than as a getter property. Is there a way to tell the client to see it as a property? (Or must I just abandon the use of properties in service contracts?)

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, which make a lot of sense. "No" is a very useful answer. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In WCF, all you can do is send messages between client and server.

The client never has direct rpc-style access to the server object - therefore, you cannot surface properties or anything like that.

All you can do is serialize messages and send them to a method with the `[OperationContract]` on them. This cannot be applied to setter methods of properties, I believe.

Marc

Answer (score 4):

No SOAP web services anywhere in the world supports properties. There is no way to describe a property in a WSDL. Web Services are about operations (methods) only.

Answer (score 1):

A Web Service doesn't expose properties. It only exposes its methods that can be called by the clients (a Web Service is stateless...so having properties really doesn't makes sense because they'd always be the initial value).

Answer (score 1):

Use the DataMember attribute.

```
[DataMember]
int SomeProperty
{
   get;
}
```

You'll have to make sure that your object is serializable.

This will create a complex type for your object and add an element like so...

```
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="SomeProperty" type="xs:int" />
```

Comment: [http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl#_types](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl#_types) Describes the type system used by Web Services. This is supported by WCF using the `DataContract` and `DataMember` attributes on your object.